# How to properly find correct indexes of float in byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, queue

I have the following byte array which is coming in from a BLE device. Each time I read the byte array I receive different cvhunks of the byte array, sometimes 3, 7, 16, 17,etc. I have implemented a queue to make sure that I receive all of the data. However I am having trouble finding the start of the byte array. I am sending a null terminator byte(0x00) on the other side at the beginning of the array before I send 4 float variables.

Sending this byte array repeating in the stream:

00 3F 8F CB 92 3F C8 AD AC 3F F4 7E 28 3F 8E 59 4B

which are the float numbers 1.1234, 1.5678, 1.9101, 1.1121

The problem is that I my code can't find the beginning of each bytea sequence and the end to convert to the correct float.

Here is my current code:

I have checked the endinaess and it is correct.

```
static float EnterDataQueue (byte[] bytes) {
    //Array.Reverse(bytes);
    ArduinoHM10Test aTest = new ArduinoHM10Test ();


    //always load the data byte array in full
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
        aTest.myQueue.Enqueue (bytes[i]);
    }

    //Dequeue the queue and check if 4 bytes have been dequeued
    //Dequeue and check for 0
    Debug.Log ("ValueCheckQueueLength1: " + aTest.myQueue.Count.ToString ());

    if (aTest.myQueue.Count >= 16) {

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 4) {
            byte tempVal = aTest.myQueue.Dequeue ();
            if (tempVal != 00) {
                byteArray[i] = tempVal;
                i++;
            } else {
                i = 0;
            }

        }

        PrintHexBytes (byteArray);
        aTest.floatnum = BitConverter.ToSingle (byteArray, 0);

        Debug.Log ("ValueCheckQueueLength2: " + aTest.myQueue.Count.ToString ());
        Debug.Log ("ValueCheckfloatnumDataQueue: " + aTest.floatnum.ToString ());
    }

    return aTest.floatnum;

}
```

Can you please help me correct my code so that my floats are converted correctly and not someting like 1.06335e-14 instead of 1.1121 (taking the bytes 283F8E59 or some other sequence).

Comment: You need to step through your code in the debugger and give a more precise location of your error.  What does `byteArray` contain at the end?  Is the queue content correct at the beginning?

Comment: @Grim I am not receiving the correct float number on the line "aTest.floatnum = BitConverter.ToSingle (byteArray, 0);"

Comment: So you're saying that the built-in .NET BitConverter isn't doing what you want it to do?  Have you read through the MSDN page on BitConverter.ToSingle() ?  Try some test data (perhaps use the examples on the MS page) and check that your Arduino is encoding the original floats using the same method (not just endianness).  IIRC it's IEEE - which is not straight-forward.

Comment: @Grim the wrong bytes are being taken and I want to allocate the correct ones to byteArray to convert. I'm not sure if you saw the last comment line "Can you please help me correct my code so that my floats are converted correctly and not someting like 1.06335e-14 instead of 1.1121 (taking the bytes 283F8E59 or some other sequence)." If you split the receing HEX which I get on the C# side you can see that I'm receiving the correct data. (00 3F 8F CB 92 3F C8 AD AC 3F F4 7E 28 3F 8E 59 4B)

Comment: 'Hex' bytes 28 3F 8E 59 equate to 'Decimal' bytes 40, 63, 142, 89.  Converting those to a float => `BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] {40, 63, 142, 89}, 0)` gives an output of 5.004861e+15.  I ask again, how is the data being encoded at the other end?  I'm guessing it's not the C# line `BitConverter.GetBytes()` ??

Comment: Hi Grim, sorry maybe I didn't make it clear. I can get 1.1121 sometimes, then sometimes not (i.e. - I get a very large or small decimal...not to do with endianess). I need to find a way so that my program can find the start of the array at 00, omit this value and then convert the next 4 bytes and the next 4 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples were incorrect; neither of us can count - the LAST FOUR hex digits in your example are 3F 8E 59 4B.  This equates to decimal numbers 63, 142, 89, 75.
Running this through C# gives;

`BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] {63, 142, 89, 75}, 0)` an answer of 14257727.

However, if we reverse the bytes;

`BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] {75, 89, 142, 63}, 0)` we get 1.1121.

So essentially your byte order is incorrect.  Either load the data in reverse at the other end, or dequeue the data into the byte array backwards; such as

```
if (tempVal != 00) {
    byteArray[3 - i] = tempVal;
    i++;
```

(Completely untested, but I hope you get the idea).  I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Hi Grim, sorry maybe I didn't make it clear. I can get 1.1121 sometimes, then sometimes not (i.e. - I get a very large or small decimal...not to do with endianess). I need to find a way so that my program can find the start of the array at 00, omit this value and then convert the next 4 bytes and the next 4 and so on.

Comment: It's a queue.  Dequeue a byte.  If it's zero, dequeue the next 4 and convert.

Comment: How could I be sure that I'm starting at the first byte of a float if I pull mid stream?

Comment: It's not mid stream; it's after your 0x00 start byte - which you've defined in your protocol.  If your start byte is not reliable (which it isn't) then change it something else, like 0x02 0xFF 0xFF 0x02 (start of transmission, two 'max' bytes, then another STx) - this creates a more unique, less random pattern to search for.

Comment: The bottom line is your protocol is far too simple to be guaranteed reliable - if you want that kind of thing, you need a start, end, checksum and other gubbins.